# Call a JS function in column of a kendo grid

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with multiple columns and multiple rows. I want the last column to show calculated data. I want to make an AJAX method take ID and get some data from the database and show it in this column (all rows). How can I do that?

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: ds,
  columns: [{
    field: 'ID',
    title: '#',
    hidden: true
  }, {
    title: 'Test',
    filterable: false,
    width: "130px",
    ClientTemplate: "#=MyMethod(ID)#"
  }]
}).data("kendoGrid");

function MyMethod(ID) {
  var returnData = 0;
  $.get('@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")', {
    Id: ID
  }, function(response) {
    returnData = response;
  });
  return returnData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you don't do that.

The reason I say this is because you would trigger an ajax call for each row and there can be lots of rows which potentially means a long delay before you can show something to the user.

You most likely have one database call to return the data. In that one call, do any calculation required, if it's only a total, the database itself can deal with this in a very fast manner. So do your calculation there, return the calculated field as an extra field in your dataset and then your UI only has to show a field which is already calculated.

It's going to be much quicker and a much better user experience as well.

Comment: ok , but what is wrong in my code?
how can i do what i want ?

Comment: I just told you how, update your database call to return one extra calculated field. Then you don't need to call anything in the gridI don't know how much clearer I can say that.

Comment: ok , if i want to call method in column how can i do that ?
is there way to do that ?